# Who am I at the server side of Google RPC (gRPC)?

Tags: authentication, grpc

I am authenticating the client using gRPC's [client-side SSL/TLS](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/#using-client-side-ssltls). How do I find out on the server side which user it is?

Comment: Which gRPC language are you using?

Comment: @San P: I am using C++ and C#. Shouldn't it be not a cross-platform way?

Comment: The actual API to access TLS attributes is language dependent but the functionality and of course on the wire protocol are language independent (cross platform?).

Answer (score 0):

Use context->Auth_Context()->FindPropertyValues("x509_pem_cert") in C++ to get the peer's (client's) certificate and the client id (SAN?) in the cert.